# Экспорт в highcharts работает не корректно

Tags: highcharts

Есть график построенный на библиотеке highcharts [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на верхнюю строку "Вероятность сияния" под ней иконки появляются при kp>3

Все работает, все прекрасно, но при экспорте (встроенная библиотека от highcharts) эти иконки не отображаются на сохраняемой картинке

Вот картинка получаемая при экспорте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы экспортировалось как есть в оригинале?

На их форуме англосацком задал вопрос, но то-ли мой английский плох, то-ли не так что-то написал - модерацию не прошел. Может тут помогут?

Оригинал подопытный  hibiny.com/info/weather/murmansk/geomagnit/

Добавляю иконку через дополнительный xAxis

```
{
            linkedTo: 0,
            //title: {text: 'Вероятность северного сияния ', y:30, zIndex: '-1', style: {fontSize: '11px'}},
            categories: [  '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 'green' , '' , 'green' , 'color' , 'color' , 'color' , 'green' , 'green' , 'color' , '' , '' , 'green' ],
            labels: {
                    rotation: 0,
                    x:0, y:15,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function()
                      {
                    if(this.value == "green")
                        return '<img src="/images/2020/weather/icons/aurora/green.png" width="25">';
                    else if(this.value == "color")
                        return '<img src="/images/2020/weather/icons/aurora/color.png" width="25">';
                    else
                        return this.value;
                      }
                    },
            opposite: true,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            tickLength: 40
            }
```

Comment: как именно вы добавляете иконку на график? P.S. кстати для создателей таких вотермарков есть отдельный котел ну вы знаете где

Comment: подправил текст с методом отображения иконок. PS. а что делать? тырят без указания источника - только так, подругому не помогает

Comment: `тырят без указания источника`, так чтобы источник был виден, но не мешал смотреть на графики - вы бы еще красным надпись бы сделали :))) - например можно сделать надпись еще более блеклой (раза в 2-3) и разместить ее только на нижней части, тогда через нее гарантированно будут проходить бины гистограммы, так что надпись не вырезать, просмотру графиков надпись мешать не будет, но идентифицировать картинку будет можно - если ваша цель именно иметь доказательство, что эта картинка ваша

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-meteogram#https://www.yr.no/place/United_Kingdom/England/London/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml как в демках то не хотите сделать? иконки лучше смотрятся у значений, а не где-то наверху, имхо.

Comment: пробовал так. не понравилось. но если решения не найду - придется сделать  как у норгов

Comment: я про суть, что там не лейблы к оси используется, а вывод иконки в нужном месте. поменяете место на свое.

Comment: хех, я не понимаю что происходит - скопировал код графика на https://jsfiddle.net/fr13790q/  - экспорт работает как надо, картинки сохраняются, у меня на сайте все тоже самое, но с кучей моего кода (который не должен мешать) - нифига :((((